# How does Ubuntu determine a package to be installed?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Other than extracting files specific to the package in their proper directories and running whatever scripts defined in it, does `apt`/`dpkg` maintain a separate record of what has been installed successfully?

I'm considering merging the root directories of separate containers, so I'm wondering what's going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `dpkg` records entries of packages installed in the system. The file it maintains is `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

```
/var/lib/dpkg/status
      Statuses  of  available packages. This file contains information
      about whether a package is marked for removing or  not,  whether
      it  is  installed  or  not,  etc.  See section INFORMATION ABOUT
      PACKAGES for more info.

      The status file is backed up daily in /var/backups.  It  can  be
      useful if it's lost or corrupted due to filesystems troubles.
```